# Which PJSIP library level to use for B2BUA

Tags: sip, pjsip

I'm considering using PJSIP to create a B2BUA. There are a number of different layers/wrappers in the PJSIP project and I'm wondering what the right layer to use is.

While PJSIPUA2 makes call management simpler as an endpoint, it appears that I lose the level of control needed of the SIP dialog needed to coordinate the 2 legs of the call.

What is the right PJSIP library level to use for a B2BUA?